# Scala RDD calling filter function conditionally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a generic function to read RDD and generate Dataframe. I will call this function twice, one with the filter another without. Is there a way to make my function more elegant?

```
def generateDF(rawdata: Type, applyFilter: Boolean): DataFrame = {
  val rdd = if(applyFilter == true) {
          sc.sequenceFile[Array[Byte], String](rawdata)
              .values
              .filter(filterCondition)
              .map(parser.parseData)
              .map(addColumnFunction)    

        } else{
           sc.sequenceFile[Array[Byte], String](rawdata)
             .values
             .map(parser.parseData)
             .map(addColumnFunction)
        }

  createDataFrame(rdd, outputFieldNames)  
}
```

Calling the function:

```
val dfWithFilter    = generateDF(rawdata, true)
val dfWithoutFilter = generateDF(rawdata, false)
```

I am new to Scala, the above function is working as designed, but I would like to learn more best practices against the above situation. For example, how I can only write this whole block of code only once rather than repeating it?

```
 sc.sequenceFile[Array[Byte], String](rawdata)
   .values
   .map(parser.parseData)
   .map(addColumnFunction)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
   val rdd0 = sc.sequenceFile[Array[Byte], String](rawdata)
    .values
    .map(parser.parseData)
    .map(addColumnFunction)

  val rdd = if(applyFilter == true) {
    rdd0.filter(filterCondition)
  } else { rdd0 }

  createDataFrame(rdd, outputFieldNames)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me. By doing that are we using more memory to make the code look better? We will need to create two giant RDD before we can filter the data.